# Calculating the orientation of a figure to straighten it out (in python)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-manipulation

I have a code that calculates the orientation of a figure and a function that straightens the figure out based on the calculated orientation. When I run the code, the orientation seems to be fine, but when the function tries to straighten the figure out it looks like the figure has gotten another shape. Could there be something wrong in the code?

The Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('path_to_input_image',0) 
edges = cv2.Canny(img,1,2,70,3)

img = edges 
y, x = np.nonzero(img)

x = x - np.mean(x) 
y = y - np.mean(y)
coords = np.vstack([x, y])

cov = np.cov(coords) 
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(cov) 

sort_indices = np.argsort(evals)[::-1] 
x_v1, y_v1 = evecs[:, sort_indices[0]]  
x_v2, y_v2 = evecs[:, sort_indices[1]]

scale = 30
plt.plot([x_v1*-scale*2, x_v1*scale*2], 
         [y_v1*-scale*2, y_v1*scale*2], color='red')
plt.plot([x_v2*-scale, x_v2*scale],
         [y_v2*-scale, y_v2*scale], color='blue')
plt.plot(x, y, 'k.')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()  
plt.show()

def rechtzetten(x_v1,y_v1,coords):
    theta = np.arctan((x_v1)/(y_v1))
    rotation_mat =np.matrix([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],[np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]])
    transformed_mat = rotation_mat*coords


    x_transformed, y_transformed = transformed_mat.A

    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0.,0.,1.,1.])
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axes(ax)
    ax = plt.plot(x_transformed,y_transformed)

    plt.savefig("ja.png",pdi=300)
    plt.show(ax)
    #plt.savefig("rotation.png") 
    img3 = cv2.imread('ja.png',100)
    edges2 = cv2.Canny(img3,1,4)

    cv2.imwrite('rotated_with_border.png', edges2)
    return transformed_mat, edges2

transformed_mat, edges = rechtzetten(x_v1,y_v1,coords)
```

The input image I used:

[image]

The output I get:

[image]

The first figure of the outputs shows the orientation using the blue and red axis.
The second figure of the output should be the straightened out version of the first figure.

*By straighten out I mean match the blue and red axis on the first figure with the x and y axes on a basic coordinate system.

Comment: I cannot answer your question. Perhaps the rotation matrix is transposed. But why do you not just get the rotated bounding rectangle (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect). Then its 4 corners. Then getRotationMatrix2D. Then warpAffine. See for example https://gist.github.com/Ankita-Das/82bce39b35d1bbeca2ce87c4e8aba33d and https://jdhao.github.io/2019/02/23/crop_rotated_rectangle_opencv/

Comment: I don't know what happens at your transformation but you should use opencv getRotationMatrix2D command with "theta" you estimated and then give the output of this command to opencv warpAffine command.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do deskewing using the rotated bounding rectangle in Python/OpenCV

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("object.png")

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold the grayscale image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,0)

# find outer contour
cntrs = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]

# get rotated rectangle from contour
rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(cntrs[0])
box = cv2.boxPoints(rotrect)
box = np.int0(box)

# draw rotated rectangle on copy of img
rot_bbox = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(rot_bbox,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)

# get orientation angle relative to horizontal of the rotated rectangle
angle = rotrect[-1]

# from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/
# the `cv2.minAreaRect` function returns values in the
# range [-90, 0); as the rectangle rotates clockwise the
# returned angle tends to 0 -- in this special case we
# need to add 90 degrees to the angle
if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)

# otherwise, just take the negative of the angle to make
# it positive
else:
    angle = -angle

print(angle,"deg")

# negate the angle for deskewing
neg_angle = -angle

# Get rotation matrix
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, neg_angle, scale=1.0)

# rotate the image to deskew it
deskewed = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)


cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("ROTATED BBOX", rot_bbox)
cv2.imshow("DESKEWED", deskewed)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("object_deskewed.png", deskewed)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @fmw42, I was trying something like this when I saw your first comment but I didn't succeed. Now I see how you've done this, I can come to the conclusion that I've tried to handle this problem on a way too complicated manner.