# Rotating the images to straight orientation

Tags: python, opencv, image-rotation

I have been trying a lot on rotating images of the supermarket bills that are in different angles to straighten them, but I am facing problems in doing so. I have tried the below way to rotate but the problem is the images get rotated only to the nearest possible axis. I mean if the angle of orientation is between 0 to 90 degrees, then the image is rotated to 0 degrees (straight). If the angle of orientation is between 90 to 180 degrees, then the image is rotated to 90 degrees. If in between 180 and 270, rotates to 180, and if in between 270 and 360 it rotates to 270 degrees.

Below are some different possibilities of an image orientation:

> [60_degree_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaMB2.jpg) [120_degree_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XTSi.jpg) [240_degree_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqT9q.jpg)
> [330_degree_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYRwB.jpg)

And I wish the output images of all the above 4 images would be the same as below straight
image:

> [desired_output_of_all_4_images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emGHx.jpg)

PS: I would not want to enter degrees of rotation manually in the code but somehow the code must be able to do the rotation by itself to desired output. And the above approach is based on text orientation considering that all the text is in the same orientation.

Any other possible way and any help are much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code for cross-checking:

> [Please_click_this_link_for_the_code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k7fwhOSJT2S0UIgl1NgFOzFaKtxcaQ52/view?usp=sharing)

> 

Comment: Do post your code here directly, rather than linking to it

Comment: I would suggest that you crop the white receipt from the background and make the outside white. Then use FFT processing to get the orientation angle and rotate the image straight according to that. See  https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/ You will have to use OCR to determine if the text is right-side-up or up-side-down.

Comment: Thanks, @fmw42 for your comment. I will work around the possible solution you have provided and let you know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello @fmw42, I just tried to rotate the images with the code in the answers you mentioned here in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450102/calculating-the-orientation-of-a-figure-to-straighten-it-out-in-python, but I did not succeed and the output image is the same as the input image. Can you please help me out here? For now, I just need help in straightening the images, irrespective that if the image is exactly staright or flipped.

Comment: Post a new question with one image that does not work and the code you used. Then I can see what might be wrong. Did you threshold to get a binary image of the receipt and get the rotation of the binary image. Then rotate the original image.

Comment: Hello @fmw42, I have posted a new question along with the code in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69523911/how-to-straighten-the-images-given-any-orientation-of-the-images with the images attached as links since StackOverflow does not allow me to post them directly. Sorry for the late, and I look forward to your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46732132/8609909 It can be done via HoughLines, more information here

Answer (score 1):

You have, basically, two possibilities.

If you *know* your input format is portrait (taller than wider) you can keep rotating until you get a portrait output format.  When you get that, rotate by 180 as well and keep the two: one of them will be upside down.  Extract a small region gauranteed to have text in it (say the middle 200px) and ocr both samples: one will have disproportionately higher numbers of words in it: this is the correct orientation; return this format.

If you do *not* know your input format is portrait, you have to do this with *four* possibilities, ocring a sample every time, and returning the one with the greatest number of hits.

Even if you do not intend to OCR the final images, OCR is still the quickest, most reliable means to determine that *text* is the right way up.

Comment: Perhaps, but no image library is magically going to be able to work out what the 'right way up' is for an image without being told.