# How to straighten the images given any orientation of the images

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, image-rotation

I have tried an algorithm to rotate the images, but it doesn't help in straightening my images given the image can have any orientation from 0 to 180/360 degrees.

Example images:

Image 1:

[image: img_1_75]

Image 2:

[image: img_2_90]

Image 3:

[image: img_3_45]

My code:

```
# import the necessary packages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import copy

def plt_imshow(title, image):
   # display the image
   plt.imshow(image)
   plt.title(title)
   plt.grid(False)
   plt.show()

args = {
"image": "C:/Users/tskta/Desktop/Images rotation/all 
rotations/75.png"}

# load the image from disk
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

#convert the image to greyscale and flip the foreground and 
background
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | 
              cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

#grab the x,y coordinates of all pixel values that are greater than 
zero
#and form a rotating bounding box
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]
print(angle)

if -45 > angle >-89:
    angle = -(90 + angle)
elif angle == -90.0:
    angle = -angle
else:
    angle = -angle 

print(angle) 

# rotate the image to deskew it
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h),
          flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

# draw the correction angle on the image so we can validate it
cv2.putText(rotated, "Angle: {:.2f} degrees".format(angle),
    (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# show the output image
print("[INFO] angle: {:.3f}".format(angle))
plt_imshow("Input", image)
plt_imshow("Rotated", rotated)
cv2.imwrite("Downloads/rotated.png", rotated)
```

Comment: previous iteration of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69404020/rotating-the-images-to-straight-orientation

Comment: What results did you get?  Were you able to cleanly separate the bill from the background?

Comment: Your images show several issues that the simple code may not handle. 1) You have two backgrounds - white and textures  2) you have texture backgrounds 3) you have more than one bill in the image. 4) your code does not seem to take into account that your result needs to be portrait mode. 5) These techniques may simply rotate so that the text is right side up or up side down. So you would need OCR to tell if the text is in the correct position and not up side down.

Comment: I assume you are not trying to totally isolate the white bill, but are extracting the rectangle of the bill or the texture background. So I think that should work as your code is expressed. But the main thing is you need to take into account that you want a portrait mode orientation for the output. The code you have, I may simple rotate to the nearest 90 deg orientation. I will have to run your code later today when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python/OpenCV code looks fine except that the angle test does not take into account that the object is going to need to be rotated to portrait mode.

The following does that by computing the direction of the edge with the largest length and then aligning (unrotating) to the vertical (Y) axis.

The code below takes a white rectangle and rotates it between -90 and 90 in 10 deg increments. The assumption is that the scan of the documents will be such that the top of the bill is in the top half of the image, thus satisfying the assumption.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# unrotation to portrait mode

# read input
img = cv2.imread('vertical_rect.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# compute center
cx = ww // 2
cy = hh // 2

# rotated input in range -90 to 90 inclusive
# assume scanned so always in that range
# do unrotation by using the longest edge of rectangle to find the direction 
# and unrotate so that it aligns with the vertical (Y) axis upwards
for rotation in range(-90,100,10):

    # rotate image
    matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cx,cy), rotation, 1.0)
    img_rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img, matrix, (ww, hh), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

    # convert to gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rotated, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # threshold (must be convex, so use morphology to close up if needed)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # find all non-zero pixel coordinates
    # swap x and y for conversion from numpy y,x to opencv x,y ordering via transpose
    coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh.transpose() > 0))

    # get minAreaRect and its vertices
    rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)
    pts = cv2.boxPoints(rotrect)
    #print(pts)
    
    list = []
    # compute edge lengths and directions (in range -90 to 90) and put into list
    polygon = img_rotated.copy()
    for i in range(0,4):
        i1 = i
        i2 = i+1 if i!=3 else 0
        pt1 = pts[i1]
        pt2 = pts[i2]
        pt1x = pt1[0]
        pt2x = pt2[0]
        pt1y = pt1[1]
        pt2y = pt2[1]
        length = math.sqrt( (pt2x-pt1x)*(pt2x-pt1x) + (pt2y-pt1y)*(pt2y-pt1y) )
        direction = (180/math.pi)*math.atan2( (pt2y-pt1y), (pt2x-pt1x) )
        list.append([length, direction, pt1])
        
        # optional: draw lines around box points on input (rotated)
        # points start at left most point (and top most to break ties)
        # and go clockwise around rectangle
        # first point is blue and second point is green to show direction
        x1 = int(pt1x)
        y1 = int(pt1y)
        x2 = int(pt2x)
        y2 = int(pt2y)
        if i == 0:
            cv2.circle(polygon,(x1,y1),7,(255,0,0),-1)
            cv2.circle(polygon,(x2,y2),5,(0,255,0),-1)
            cv2.line(polygon, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,0,255), 2)
        else:
            cv2.line(polygon, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,0,255), 2)
                
    # sort list on length with largest first
    def takeFirst(elem):
        return elem[0]
    list.sort(key=takeFirst, reverse=True)
    
    # get direction of largest length and correct to -90 to 90 range
    item = list[0]
    dir = item[1]
    if dir < -90:
        dir = dir + 180
    if dir > 90:
        dir = dir - 180
                
    # correct to portrait mode
    # if dir is negative or zero, then add 90; otherwise subtract 90
    # dir = 0 occurs for both 0 and 90, so both cannot be determined -- pick one
    if dir <= 0:
        unrotate = dir + 90
    else:
        unrotate = dir - 90
        
    print("initial rotation=", rotation, "edge direction=", dir, "unrotation angle=", unrotate)
    
    # unrotate image
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cx, cy), unrotate, 1.0)
    img_unrotated = cv2.warpAffine(img_rotated, M, (ww, hh), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

    #cv2.imshow('img_rotated', img_rotated)
    cv2.imshow('polygon', polygon)
    cv2.imshow('img_unrotated', img_unrotated)
    cv2.waitKey()

    # optional save output
    #cv2.imwrite("vertical_rect_{0}.png".format(rotation), img_unrotated)

Results:

initial rotation= -90 edge direction= 0.0 unrotation angle= 90.0
initial rotation= -80 edge direction= -10.024489033132815 unrotation angle= 79.97551096686719
initial rotation= -70 edge direction= -19.922231300954746 unrotation angle= 70.07776869904525
initial rotation= -60 edge direction= -30.000354626107335 unrotation angle= 59.99964537389266
initial rotation= -50 edge direction= -39.98688344835102 unrotation angle= 50.01311655164898
initial rotation= -40 edge direction= -50.00064126059898 unrotation angle= 39.99935873940102
initial rotation= -30 edge direction= -60.00891266459192 unrotation angle= 29.991087335408082
initial rotation= -20 edge direction= -70.07776869904525 unrotation angle= 19.92223130095475
initial rotation= -10 edge direction= -79.97551600323786 unrotation angle= 10.024483996762143
initial rotation= 0 edge direction= 90.0 unrotation angle= 0.0
initial rotation= 10 edge direction= 79.97550927006476 unrotation angle= -10.024490729935238
initial rotation= 20 edge direction= 70.07776869904525 unrotation angle= -19.92223130095475
initial rotation= 30 edge direction= 59.99507091100694 unrotation angle= -30.00492908899306
initial rotation= 40 edge direction= 50.013119348261796 unrotation angle= -39.986880651738204
initial rotation= 50 edge direction= 39.99936207636015 unrotation angle= -50.00063792363985
initial rotation= 60 edge direction= 29.991085160541278 unrotation angle= -60.008914839458726
initial rotation= 70 edge direction= 19.922231300954746 unrotation angle= -70.07776869904525
initial rotation= 80 edge direction= 10.02448431018454 unrotation angle= -79.97551568981547
initial rotation= 90 edge direction= 0.0 unrotation angle= 90.0
```

Comment: Hello @fmw42, thanks for your valuable time and code! I cant figure out how to save the image which is in portrait mode though

Comment: Why do you need to save the resulting portrait mode from my script as it is the same as the input? I can add that code, if really needed, but I don't understand the motivation

Comment: Yes, your input is of portrait mode but I want to try with different images which are also not portrait. So, am in need of that part of the code to save the images. Hope you understand.

Comment: I have added the code at the end of script after the cv2.waitKey(). It is commented out, but you can uncomment if you want it.

Comment: Thanks for your help @fmw42

Comment: Is it possible to only save images that are in portrait modes rather than all the output images @fmw42

Comment: If you start with image that are tall, then the image is expected to be portrait and will always end up portrait. If you do not know that the images are portrait or landscape to start, then how can the computer know which you want it to be? So no, in that case. You have to give it a clue whether portrait or landscape to start. If that does not answer your question and I have misunderstood, please clarify further your image situation.